# Mavericks Download Icon Error

Tags: macos, google-chrome, data-transfer, desktop

I just upgraded to OSX Mavericks and now when I try to download something the icon that shows a loading bar while it's downloading doesn't change back to normal after it's done: 
[image: broken icon][image: clearly downloaded]

I'm using the most up-to-date chrome and I changed my default download location to desktop (both of these have worked fine consistently in the past)

I can double click the zip and it unpacks totally fine, it really seems to just be the desktop icon, but it's still frustrating. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Is this only with the .zip files ?

Comment: nope. jpg and pdf's too

Comment: where did you get that square icon from ?

Comment: what square icon are you talking about?